# I want to sort the hash in the array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

```
a = [{"name"=> "ted","age"=>1}, 
     {"name"=> "mika","age"=>2},
     {"name"=> "bob","age"=>0}]
```

How do I can sort the a is an array in age order (ascending order) with ruby program?

I would like to be the following.

```
a = [{"name"=> "bob","age"=>0},
     {"name"=> "ted","age"=>1},
     {"name"=> "mika","age"=>2}]
```

Comment: `a.sort_by { |h| h["age"] }`. That's all. See [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

Comment: great.thanks a lot!

Comment: @CarySwoveland Should bump that to an answer.

Comment: benchmark for sort_by and sort https://gist.github.com/AjayBarot/69ae1c0dc6b7de28d9bd4af765a1fce5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cary Swoveland told in comment,

```
a.sort_by { |h| h["age"] }
```

I could do as above.thanks.